# Adding a gate to a hollow post

Tags: fence, gate-post

I want to add a 48" gate to an existing vinyl 4x4 post that has nothing in it. Should I fill it with concrete or add a 4x4 wood post for added support

Comment: Can you get the vinyl post out of the ground? Does it fit a 4x4 (3.5x3.5 actual) post?

Comment: What is currently supporting the vinyl post, how is it installed?